# Every checkboxes are being checked when you select only one of them

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've created a button that allows the user to add a credit card, the cards are being added to a Listview.builder. 
The problem is that when I have multiple cards and I select one, it selects all of them, it's probably a state problems but I didn't find (yet) how to fix it, here is the dartpad : [dartpad][1] of my code if you can check it and maybe show me what I'm doing wrong, it's probably failing inside the buildBody but I'm not really sure and I have not successfully found a solution yet.
You simply have to tap two times on 'Add a card' and you will see when checking one of them, both will get selected.

For some reason the link isnt working through the shortcut so here it is https://dartpad.dev/b0aaaa2901aa3ac67426d9bdd885abb1:

Comment: please add some code

Comment: @ByteMe I've added it, idk why StackOverflow wasn't showing my link correctly

Comment: You use the same _isSelected for all the checkboxes, try to create a List<bool> where each index represents the state of each checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your dartpad code to get the behaviour you are trying to achive:
The code is provided below:

The issue was that you are using the same `bool` value `_isSelected` for the two `Checkboxes`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: InformationsBancairesPage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InformationsBancairesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InformationsBancairesPageState createState() =>
      _InformationsBancairesPageState();
}

class _InformationsBancairesPageState extends State<InformationsBancairesPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Payer ou recevoir un paiement'.toUpperCase(),
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            InputAddCarte(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InputAddCarte extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputAddCarteState createState() => _InputAddCarteState();
}

class _InputAddCarteState extends State<InputAddCarte> {
  // create a list of bool values for your checkboxes
  List<bool> _selectedList = [false, false];
  int value = 0;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  _addCard() {
    setState(() {
      value = value + 1;
      print(value);
    });
  }

  Widget buildBody(BuildContext context, int indexClicked) {
    return LabeledCheckbox(
      label: 'Card credit',
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      // pass the value of the checkbox at the selected index
      value: _selectedList[indexClicked],
      onChanged: (bool newValue) {
        setState(() {
      // pass the value of the checkbox at the selected index
          _selectedList[indexClicked] = newValue;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ButtonTheme(
          minWidth: 250,
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Color(0xff00cc99),
            child: Text(
              'ADD A CARD'.toUpperCase(),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
            ),
            onPressed: _addCard,
          ),
        ),
        // Show the cards when you press 'Ajouter une carte'
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: this.value,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int value) {
            // display two cards maximum
            if (value < 2) {
             // pass the index of the selected checkbox
              return buildBody(context, value);
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),
        ButtonTheme(
          minWidth: 250,
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: Text(
              'Delete a card'.toUpperCase(),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

// Create custom checkbox for the list of cards
class LabeledCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  const LabeledCheckbox({
    this.label,
    this.padding,
    this.value,
    this.onChanged,
  });

  final String label;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final bool value;
  final Function onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        onChanged(!value);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: padding,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: Text(label)),
            Checkbox(
              value: value,
              onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                onChanged(newValue);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! I was also thinking of that but my skills didn't allow me to find a way to correct it since I'm pretty new to flutter! I will accept your response asap!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Happy Fluttering :). You can accept the answer if you found it helpful @StefanYYC